# SpeechToText IBM Watson ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, android, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Im having problem with testing IBM Watson SpeechToText Api.

```
  SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
        service.setUsernameAndPassword("<UserName>", "<Password>");

        File audio = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                +MEDIA_FOLDER+"/myaudio.amr");

        SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio).execute();
        System.out.println(transcript);
```

im getting `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` error at `SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();` line

#### Error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.fexcon.voicetotext.MainActivity.processAudioIBM(MainActivity.java:190)
at com.fexcon.voicetotext.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:100)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePatternCharacter(SimpleDateFormat.java:314)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.validatePattern(SimpleDateFormat.java:303)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:356)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:249)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.DateDeserializer.<init>(DateDeserializer.java:52)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.registerTypeAdapters(GsonSingleton.java:53)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.createGson(GsonSingleton.java:42)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.util.GsonSingleton.getGsonWithoutPrettyPrinting(GsonSingleton.java:76)
at com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud.speech_to_text.v1.SpeechToText.<clinit>(SpeechToText.java:119)
at com.fexcon.voicetotext.MainActivity.processAudioIBM(MainActivity.java:190) 
at com.fexcon.voicetotext.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:100) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5184) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20910) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

Comment: Is service.setUsernameAndPassword(); your custom function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

It happend only to lower level SDK devices. once i added latest `speech-to-text` library, it solved. `'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:speech-to-text:3.8.1-SNAPSHOT'` insted of `'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:speech-to-text:3.8.0'`
[Info](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/issues/681).

---

Today i started another android project from scratch and didnt get that above runtime exception. and i have managed to get the text out of wave file.

Example :

```
 final SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();
            service.setUsernameAndPassword("<YourUsername>", "<Password>");

            final File audio = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/about_time.wav");

            final RecognizeOptions options = new RecognizeOptions.Builder()
                    .continuous(false)
                    .model("en-US_NarrowbandModel")
                    .interimResults(true)
                    .contentType(HttpMediaType.AUDIO_WAV)
                    .build();



            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    SpeechResults transcript = service.recognize(audio, options).execute();
                    System.out.println(transcript);
                }
            }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your setUsernameAndPassword is wrong.
it should be: setCredentials(String username, String password)
unless it is your custom function.

At the bottom of the link, find the function: setCredentials(String username, String password)

Also you need to initialize shared instance and use it,

```
     /**
     * Init the shared instance with the context
     * @param uri
     * @param ctx
     * @param sc
     */
    public void initWithContext(URI uri, Context ctx, SpeechConfiguration sc){
        this.setHostURL(uri);
        this.appCtx = ctx;
        this.sConfig = sc;
    }
```

Try following this step provided in the quick start guide.

```
private boolean initSTT() {
     // initialize the connection to the Watson STT service
     String username = getString(R.string.STTdefaultUsername);
     String password = getString(R.string.STTdefaultPassword);
     String tokenFactoryURL = getString(R.string.STTdefaultTokenFactory);
     String serviceURL = "wss://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api";
     SpeechConfiguration sConfig = new SpeechConfiguration(SpeechConfiguration.AUDIO_FORMAT_OGGOPUS);
     SpeechToText.sharedInstance().initWithContext(this.getHost(serviceURL), getActivity().getApplicationContext(), sConfig);
     // Basic Authentication
     SpeechToText.sharedInstance().setCredentials(username, password);
     SpeechToText.sharedInstance().setModel(getString(R.string.modelDefault));
     SpeechToText.sharedInstance().setDelegate(this);
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: No problem is coming from Line 1 `SpeechToText service = new SpeechToText();` . and setUsernameAndPassword mentioned in here. https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/speech-to-text

Comment: okay try without" new speechtotext()". Instead use sharedinstance and: SpeechToText.sharedInstance().setCredentials( "<UserName>", "<Password>" )

Comment: `setCredentials` showing me as unresolved. only `setUsernameAndPassword` works. is there any problem with my dependencies? im using `compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:speech-to-text:3.8.0'
 compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.7.2'`

Comment: I think we are using different libraries. I am using the one here : https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-android-sdk

Comment: Right. ill check on that

Comment: Yes mine is for android. Yours, I think is the java sdk?

Comment: Yes. JavaSDK. ill check with AndroidSDK. Thanks

Comment: I did look into AndroidSdk. but in documentation it has mentioned JavaSDK should also be working. any how today i started on new project and didnt get the exception. not sure what happend. now it work with JavaSDK fine